# How to Backup and Restore a Substrate Chain Running on a Server

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I am planning to publish a Substrate chain on a server, and I want to ensure that I have a reliable backup and restore process in place to prevent data loss. How can I backup and restore my Substrate chain data without losing any transactions or data in case of unexpected shutdowns or other issues?

Also, when I run a node (NPOS) on my local machine, the hard drive fills up after 2-3 hours. Will this issue occur on the mainnet, and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Stop the node and backup the data periodically, then restart the node, if you got enough space, I recommend you run another backup node for this usage
2. Increase your hard drive space or use the pruning mode, but the final solution is still increasing your hard drive space, BTW 2~3 hours is crazy it looks like that your hard drive space is pretty small, you'd better upgrade your hardware

Comment: I dont undrestand as well , what you mean about stop the node ? If i stop the node , my service will go down . Its not good for my bussines . Could you tell me what shoud i do more clear?

Comment: You have to stop the node. You can't copy the data if it is in used. if you don't want your service go down for a few mins. Buy a large hard drive. And run 2 nodes. Apply the backing action on one of them.

Comment: how much space i need for start ?

Comment: It depends on your chain size. Just check your node's db folder size.